# Statsmodel v0.12.0 FutureWarning: The parameter names will change after 0.12 is released

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, statsmodels

I have this dataset in `pandas`, the name of the dataframe is `train`:

```
date         value  
2017-01-09  0.331836
2017-01-10  0.330815
2017-01-11  0.329794
2017-01-12  0.328773
2017-01-13  0.327752
...     ...
2020-05-29  0.254081
2020-05-30  0.267420
2020-05-31  0.280758
2020-06-01  0.294097
2020-06-02  0.309384
```

The date column is the index and my late date is 2020-06-02. I use the following code to make prediction:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg,ar_select_order
f = 14
mod = ar_select_order(train[y_col].ravel(), maxlag=15)
AutoRegfit = AutoReg(train[y_col].ravel(), trend='c', lags=mod.ar_lags).fit()
AutoRegfit.predict(start=len(train),end=len(train)+f-1,dynamic=False)
```

I get :

```
 FutureWarning: The parameter names will change after 0.12 is released. Set old_names to False to use the new names now. Set old_names to True to use the old names.
```

What does it mean?

Comment: This is just a warning that the names used for variables in the summary and in other places will change starting in 0.13. You can set the parameter `old_names=False` to use the new names and stop the warning from appearing.

Comment: Thanks, where is this parameter should be? in the `AutoReg` or `predict`?

Comment: You should add this argument to `AutoReg`